# Making height and width 100% of the device

Tags: html, css, viewport-units

I want the body to have margins of like 15px and stay 100% height and width of the window, 100 vh is the same thing.

I want a welcome screen which will fit to the screen (resolution of the user) so basically the body should resize it self to the screen height and width when the user resizes the window.

Ok, so the problem is when I use 100% or vh with margin it overflows, i cannot work with hidden cuz i need the bottom part, now its okay with width because the its display block which fixes the problem for width.

`h`
https://jsfiddle.net/0dx36zb4/

Comment: try height and width auto

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `box-sizing: border-box;` along with `width: 100vw;` and `height; 100vh;`

Comment: works with paddings not margins, there still an overflow with margins

Comment: also this doesnt allow padding to the bottom

Comment: what do you need the margins for? you might have to do a workaround to get it to work.

Comment: yeah i can create 4 divs around but it would be v hard to animate, i am gonna use it for loading animation

Comment: the problem is that you cant guarantee a 100vw/vh without using a percent margin. There are workarounds like using display: table; but i dont know how well that is going to work with animating.

Answer (score 0):

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.splash {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/desktop-year-of-the-tiger-images-wallpaper.jpg  
   " class="splash" />
```

Comment: i need margins.

Comment: can you please tell me exactly which kind of screen you want?
so i cam help you.

Comment: fullscreen landing page with margins and no scrolling

Comment: @potato can you please check answer now?

Comment: yeah okay i need margins like splash with 15px margins all side

Comment: you got the answer?

Comment: @potato  - I think I get what you mean. Use a parent with padding instead of using margins. See my answer for an example and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use margin on the body, instead use a parent/child element and set padding on the parent. Margin is outside of the element, and so is not considered in the calculation - yours overflows because it is 100% of the width/height, plus 15px in each direction. Padding is inside the element and you can set the browser to consider it in your width/height specifications with the `box-sizing:border-box` property.

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="parent">
             <div id="child">
             </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
}

#parent {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding:15px;
    margin:0;
}

#child {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}
```

**EDIT**

I was also able to get your JSFiddle working so you can see an example of that if you replace your code with the code below.

```
html,body {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:15px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
section {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%; 
  margin: 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use padding and box-sizing to fix the issue. I updated your JSFiddle to work:

https://jsfiddle.net/0dx36zb4/4/

```css
  
html,body {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}

body {
  padding:15px;
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%; 
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section>
  <h1>hello</h1>
  </section>
</body>
```